# Deploymennt issues, class not found even if in pom

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

When I am trying to run my app I have the following error message :

```
cannot Deploy pro_jpa
deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [pro_jpa] : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader. Please see server.log for more details.
```

So I add this to my pom :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

But it didn't fix the issue even if it supposed to add the needed jar to the app.

I also tried to add the guava.jar to the server lib but it doesn't change anything.

If anyone has an idea thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no more this issues when I am working with version 2.3 of the web app it is only appearing when I am using version 3.0.
I am using BoneCP and glassfish so the issue may comes from it.
To solve it I need to add the jar to the domaine itself in glassfish under :
glassfish5\glassfish\domains[domain name]\lib\ext

I end with this jar :

- bonecp-0.8.0-rc1.jar
- guava-29.0-jre.jar
- mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar

Answer (score 0):

Add the runtime scope to the dependency in pom.xml, to get it available at runtime:

```
<scope>runtime</scope>
```

Comment: Hi, same issue with the runtime scope. BTW I thought that if you do not declare scope the dependency is available for all scope, am I wrong ?

Comment: Default is compile scope. It´s not quite clear how the app is structured / built / deployed. In any case, the guava jar has to be on the class path at run time (the lib directory?).